# resolve aliases in webpack.config.ts

Tags: typescript, webpack

webpack allows to write the config file with typescript, however it may contain alias paths that needed to be resolved to its mapped paths.

note that I am talking here about thecfile `webpack.config.ts` itself, not other `.ts` files

paths already defined in tsconfig.json and work well with `tsc` command.

even if you temporary used the real paths in `webpack.config.ts` file, it still complains of alias paths that these real paths request.

how to use aliases in a webpack config file?

Comment: remember that TS path aliases don't exist at runtime in NodeJS, only TSC knows what they mean, it's your job to make sure something can be required at those paths

Answer (score 1):

try with this in your file  wepack.config.ts , for each path that you need to add a new alias

```
const path = require("path");

entry: {
  ....
}, 
resolve:{
  alias:{
    Utils: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/utils'),
    Utils2: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/utils2')

  }
},
output: {..}
```